# How to handle different schema for errors in Retrofit 2?

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit2

I have an API which returns one of the following schemas:

**Success** (data found)

```
{
    item_count: 83,
    items_per_page: 25,
    offset: 25,
    items: [
        { ... },
        { ... },
        { ... },
        ...
    ]
}
```

**Failure** (no data found)

```
{
    success: false,
    error: {
        code: 200,
        message: "Server is busy"
    }
}
```

I want to use Retrofit 2 with GSON to build a wrapper around this API and convert to POJOs, however I'm uncertain how to handle the fact that the API potentially returns two entirely different schemas. For now, I have the following classes:

```
public class PaginatedResponse<T> {
    private int item_count;
    private int items_per_page;
    private int offset;
    private List<T> items;

    public PaginatedResponse<T>(int item_count, int items_per_page, int offset, List<T> items) {
        this.item_count = item_count;
        this.items_per_page = items_per_page;
        this.offset = offset;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public List<T> getItems() {
        return this.items;
    }
}
```

```
public class Item {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    // ...
}
```

Then for my API interface I have:

```
public interface API {
    @GET("items")
    Call<PaginatedResponse<Item>> getItems();
}
```

Then finally to use this I tried to say:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://localhost")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();

API api = retrofit.create(API.class);

api.getItems().enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<PaginatedResponse<Broadcast>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<PaginatedResponse<Broadcast>> call, Response<PaginatedResponse<Broadcast>> response) {
        Log.d("SUCCESS", response.body().getItems().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<PaginatedResponse<Broadcast>> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.d("FAILURE", t.toString());
    }
}
```

So long as no errors are thrown, this seems to work. But when an error is thrown, I get the following in Logcat and my app crashes:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
```

It seems like because the failure JSON lacks an `items` property, it's setting `List<Item> items` to `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like because the failure JSON lacks an items property, it's setting List items to null

Yes, It is. You're getting `NullPointerException` , because you called `toString()` on a null object. This is an expected behavior.

**Solution**

As you have different schema for `error` and `success`, you need to create **a model with both values**. Below given a minimal example,

**ResponseModel.java**

```java
class ResponseModel {

    // ERROR
    private final Boolean success;
    private final Error error;

    // SUCCESS
    private final int item_count;
    // more success values... 

    ResponseModel(Boolean success, Error error, int item_count) {
        this.success = success;
        this.error = error;
        this.item_count = item_count;
    }

    public class Error {
        private final int code;
        private final String message;

        private Error(int code, String message) {
            this.code = code;
            this.message = message;
        }

        public int getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

    }

    public Boolean getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public Error getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public int getItem_count() {
        return item_count;
    }
}
```

and in `onResponse` method, you can check if the response is success or not like this

```java
ResponseModel responseModel = response.body();

if (responseModel.getError() == null) {
    // success
    doSomethingWithSuccess(responseModel.getItem_count())
} else {
    // error
    doSomethingWithError(responseModel.getError())
}
```